# V 10.3.1 kernel crashes after an evaluation on Mac OS X El Capitan

Tags: kernel, mac-os-x, crash

I tried to solve a simple system of first order differential equations an then an algebraic system in *Mathematica* 10.3.1 on my MacBook Pro. I did't have a problem with *Mathematica* until today. Here's the code

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]

IE1[X1_, X2_, Y1_, Y2_, Φ_] := 
  Subscript[c, 111] X1*X1 + Subscript[c, 112] X1*X2 + 
   Subscript[c, 122] X2*X2 + Subscript[d, 111] Y1*Y1 + 
   Subscript[d, 112] Y1*Y2 + Subscript[d, 122] Y2*Y2 + 
   Subscript[b, 1] Φ*Φ;
E2[X1_, X2_, Y1_, Y2_, Φ_] := 
  Subscript[c, 211] X1*X1 + Subscript[c, 212] X1*X2 + 
   Subscript[c, 222] X2*X2 + Subscript[d, 211] Y1*Y1 + 
   Subscript[d, 212] Y1*Y2 + Subscript[d, 222] Y2*Y2 + 
   Subscript[b, 2] Φ*Φ;
I1[X1_, X2_, Y1_, Y2_, Φ_] := 
  Subscript[g, 111] X1*X1 + Subscript[g, 112] X1*X2 + 
   Subscript[g, 122] X2*X2 + Subscript[a, 111] Y1*Y1 + 
   Subscript[a, 112] Y1*Y2 + Subscript[a, 122] Y2*Y2 + 
   Subscript[k, 1] Φ*Φ;
I2[X1_, X2_, Y1_, Y2_, Φ_] := 
  Subscript[g, 211] X1*X1 + Subscript[g, 212] X1*X2 + 
   Subscript[g, 222] X2*X2 + Subscript[a, 211] Y1*Y1 + 
   Subscript[a, 212] Y1*Y2 + Subscript[a, 222] Y2*Y2 + 
   Subscript[k, 2] Φ*Φ;

A1 = FullSimplify[
   D[E1[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, Φ], X1]*
     D[I1[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, Φ], X1] + 
    D[E2[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, Φ], X1]*
     D[I2[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, Φ], X1]];
A2 = FullSimplify[
   D[E1[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, Φ], X1]*
     D[I1[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, Φ], X2] + 
    D[E1[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, Φ], X2]*
     D[I1[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, Φ], X1] + 
    D[E2[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, Φ], X1]*
     D[I2[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, Φ], X2] + 
    D[E2[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, Φ], X2]*
     D[I2[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, Φ], X1]];
A3 = FullSimplify[
   D[E1[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, Φ], X2]*
     D[I1[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, Φ], X2] + 
    D[E2[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, Φ], X2]*
     D[I2[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, Φ], X2]];
A4 = FullSimplify[
   D[E1[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, Φ], X1]*
     D[I1[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, Φ], Y2] + 
    D[E1[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, Φ], Y2]*
     D[I1[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, Φ], X1] + 
    D[E2[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, Φ], X1]*
     D[I2[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, Φ], Y2] + 
    D[E2[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, Φ], Y2]*
     D[I2[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, Φ], X1]];
A5 = FullSimplify[
   D[E1[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, Φ], X2]*
     D[I1[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, Φ], Y1] + 
    D[E1[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, Φ], Y1]*
     D[I1[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, Φ], X2] + 
    D[E2[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, Φ], X2]*
     D[I2[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, Φ], Y1] + 
    D[E2[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, Φ], Y1]*
     D[I2[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, Φ], X2]];
A6 = FullSimplify[
   D[E1[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, Φ], Y1]*
     D[I1[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, Φ], Y1] + 
    D[E2[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, Φ], Y1]*
     D[I2[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, Φ], Y1]];
A7 = FullSimplify[
   D[E1[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, Φ], Y2]*
     D[I1[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, Φ], Y2] + 
    D[E2[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, Φ], Y2]*
     D[I2[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, Φ], Y2]];
A8 = FullSimplify[
   D[E1[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, Φ], Y1]*
     D[I1[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, Φ], Y2] + 
    D[E1[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, Φ], Y2]*
     D[I1[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, Φ], Y1] + 
    D[E2[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, Φ], Y1]*
     D[I2[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, Φ], Y2] + 
    D[E2[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, Φ], Y2]*
     D[I2[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, Φ], Y1]];
A9 = FullSimplify[
   D[E1[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, Φ], Φ]*
     D[I1[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, Φ], Φ] + 
    D[E2[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, Φ], Φ]*
     D[I2[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, Φ], Φ]];
A10 = FullSimplify[
   D[E1[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, Φ], Φ]*
     D[I1[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, Φ], X1] + 
    D[E1[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, Φ], X1]*
     D[I1[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, Φ], Φ] + 
    D[E2[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, Φ], Φ]*
     D[I2[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, Φ], X1] + 
    D[E2[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, Φ], X1]*
     D[I2[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, Φ], Φ]];
A11 = FullSimplify[
   D[E1[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, Φ], Φ]*
     D[I1[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, Φ], X2] + 
    D[E1[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, Φ], X2]*
     D[I1[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, Φ], Φ] + 
    D[E2[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, Φ], Φ]*
     D[I2[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, Φ], X2] + 
    D[E2[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, Φ], X2]*
     D[I2[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, Φ], Φ]];
A12 = FullSimplify[
   D[E1[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, Φ], Φ]*
     D[I1[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, Φ], Y1] + 
    D[E1[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, Φ], Y1]*
     D[I1[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, Φ], Φ] + 
    D[E2[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, Φ], Φ]*
     D[I2[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, Φ], Y1] + 
    D[E2[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, Φ], Y1]*
     D[I2[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, Φ], Φ]];
A13 = FullSimplify[
   D[E1[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, Φ], Φ]*
     D[I1[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, Φ], Y2] + 
    D[E1[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, Φ], Y2]*
     D[I1[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, Φ], Φ] + 
    D[E2[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, Φ], Φ]*
     D[I2[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, Φ], Y2] + 
    D[E2[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, Φ], Y2]*
     D[I2[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, Φ], Φ]];
A14 = FullSimplify[
   D[E1[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, Φ], X1]*
     D[I1[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, Φ], Y1] + 
    D[E1[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, Φ], Y1]*
     D[I1[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, Φ], X1] + 
    D[E2[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, Φ], X1]*
     D[I2[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, Φ], Y1] + 
    D[E2[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, Φ], Y1]*
     D[I2[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, Φ], X1]];
A15 = FullSimplify[
   D[E1[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, Φ], X2]*
     D[I1[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, Φ], Y2] + 
    D[E1[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, Φ], Y2]*
     D[I1[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, Φ], X2] + 
    D[E2[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, Φ], X2]*
     D[I2[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, Φ], Y2] + 
    D[E2[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, Φ], Y2]*
     D[I2[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, Φ], X2]];

h = FullSimplify[
   E1[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, Φ]*I1[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, Φ] + 
    E2[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, Φ]*I2[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, Φ]];

FullSimplify[h*A14]

FullSimplify[h*A15]
```

And the problem begins right here. *Mathematica* compiles `A14` and `A15` perfectly and the same with my function `h`. But when I evaluate `h A14` or `h A15`, the kernel dies, and I don't know why. I tried the same code on Windows and linux and everything was right. I guess is a incompatibility of mathematica 10.3.1 and OS X El Capitan, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Worked for me...  Remove the "In[?]:=" in some of your declarations and it should produce answers.

Comment: No, it doesn't work. But thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is no false statement.  The following code works and produces answers.  I am running on Mac OS X 10.11.3 using MMA 10.3.1.0.  I broke the code into chucks for easier cutting and pasting into a notebook.

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
```

The second chunk of code...

```
E1[X1_, X2_, Y1_, Y2_, \[CapitalPhi]_] := Subscript[c, 111] X1*X1 +
Subscript[c, 112] X1*X2 + Subscript[c, 122] X2*X2 + Subscript[d, 111] Y1*Y1 +
Subscript[d, 112] Y1*Y2 + Subscript[d, 122] Y2*Y2 + 
Subscript[b, 1] \[CapitalPhi]*\[CapitalPhi];

E2[X1_, X2_, Y1_, Y2_, \[CapitalPhi]_] := Subscript[c, 211] X1*X1 + 
Subscript[c, 212] X1*X2 + Subscript[c, 222] X2*X2 + Subscript[d, 211] Y1*Y1 +
Subscript[d, 212] Y1*Y2 + Subscript[d, 222] Y2*Y2 + 
Subscript[b, 2] \[CapitalPhi]*\[CapitalPhi];

I1[X1_, X2_, Y1_, Y2_, \[CapitalPhi]_] := Subscript[g, 111] X1*X1 + 
Subscript[g, 112] X1*X2 + Subscript[g, 122] X2*X2 + 
Subscript[a, 111] Y1*Y1 + Subscript[a, 112] Y1*Y2 + 
Subscript[a, 122] Y2*Y2 + Subscript[k, 1] \[CapitalPhi]*\[CapitalPhi];

I2[X1_, X2_, Y1_, Y2_, \[CapitalPhi]_] := Subscript[g, 211] X1*X1 + 
Subscript[g, 212] X1*X2 + Subscript[g, 222] X2*X2 + 
Subscript[a, 211] Y1*Y1 + Subscript[a, 212] Y1*Y2 + 
Subscript[a, 222] Y2*Y2 + Subscript[k, 2] \[CapitalPhi]*\[CapitalPhi];
```

The third chunk of code...

```
A1 = FullSimplify[D[E1[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, \[CapitalPhi]], X1]*
 D[I1[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, \[CapitalPhi]], X1] + 
 D[E2[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, \[CapitalPhi]], X1] *
 D[I2[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, \[CapitalPhi]], X1]];

A2 = FullSimplify[D[E1[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, \[CapitalPhi]], X1]*
 D[I1[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, \[CapitalPhi]], X2] + 
 D[E1[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, \[CapitalPhi]], X2] *
 D[I1[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, \[CapitalPhi]], X1] + 
 D[E2[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, \[CapitalPhi]], X1] *
 D[I2[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, \[CapitalPhi]], X2] + 
 D[E2[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, \[CapitalPhi]], X2] *
 D[I2[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, \[CapitalPhi]], X1]];

A3 = FullSimplify[D[E1[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, \[CapitalPhi]], X2] *
 D[I1[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, \[CapitalPhi]], X2] + 
 D[E2[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, \[CapitalPhi]], X2] *
 D[I2[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, \[CapitalPhi]], X2]];

A4 = FullSimplify[D[E1[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, \[CapitalPhi]], X1] *
 D[I1[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, \[CapitalPhi]], Y2] + 
 D[E1[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, \[CapitalPhi]], Y2] *
 D[I1[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, \[CapitalPhi]], X1] + 
 D[E2[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, \[CapitalPhi]], X1] *
 D[I2[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, \[CapitalPhi]], Y2] + 
 D[E2[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, \[CapitalPhi]], Y2] *
 D[I2[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, \[CapitalPhi]], X1]];

A5 = FullSimplify[D[E1[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, \[CapitalPhi]], X2] *
 D[I1[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, \[CapitalPhi]], Y1] + 
 D[E1[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, \[CapitalPhi]], Y1] *
 D[I1[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, \[CapitalPhi]], X2] + 
 D[E2[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, \[CapitalPhi]], X2] *
 D[I2[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, \[CapitalPhi]], Y1] + 
 D[E2[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, \[CapitalPhi]], Y1] *
 D[I2[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, \[CapitalPhi]], X2]];

A6 = FullSimplify[D[E1[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, \[CapitalPhi]], Y1] *
 D[I1[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, \[CapitalPhi]], Y1] + 
 D[E2[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, \[CapitalPhi]], Y1] *
 D[I2[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, \[CapitalPhi]], Y1]];

A7 = FullSimplify[D[E1[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, \[CapitalPhi]], Y2] *
 D[I1[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, \[CapitalPhi]], Y2] + 
 D[E2[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, \[CapitalPhi]], Y2] *
 D[I2[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, \[CapitalPhi]], Y2]];

A8 = FullSimplify[D[E1[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, \[CapitalPhi]], Y1] *
 D[I1[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, \[CapitalPhi]], Y2] + 
 D[E1[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, \[CapitalPhi]], Y2] *
 D[I1[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, \[CapitalPhi]], Y1] + 
 D[E2[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, \[CapitalPhi]], Y1] *
 D[I2[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, \[CapitalPhi]], Y2] + 
 D[E2[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, \[CapitalPhi]], Y2] *
 D[I2[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, \[CapitalPhi]], Y1]];

A9 = FullSimplify[D[E1[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, \[CapitalPhi]], \[CapitalPhi]] *
 D[I1[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, \[CapitalPhi]], \[CapitalPhi]] + 
 D[E2[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, \[CapitalPhi]], \[CapitalPhi]] *
 D[I2[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, \[CapitalPhi]], \[CapitalPhi]]];

A10 = FullSimplify[D[E1[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, \[CapitalPhi]], \[CapitalPhi]] *
 D[I1[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, \[CapitalPhi]], X1] + 
 D[E1[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, \[CapitalPhi]], X1] *
 D[I1[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, \[CapitalPhi]], \[CapitalPhi]] + 
 D[E2[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, \[CapitalPhi]], \[CapitalPhi]] *
 D[I2[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, \[CapitalPhi]], X1] + 
 D[E2[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, \[CapitalPhi]], X1] *
 D[I2[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, \[CapitalPhi]], \[CapitalPhi]]];

A11 = FullSimplify[D[E1[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, \[CapitalPhi]], \[CapitalPhi]] *
 D[I1[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, \[CapitalPhi]], X2] + 
 D[E1[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, \[CapitalPhi]], X2] *
 D[I1[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, \[CapitalPhi]], \[CapitalPhi]] + 
 D[E2[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, \[CapitalPhi]], \[CapitalPhi]] *
 D[I2[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, \[CapitalPhi]], X2] + 
 D[E2[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, \[CapitalPhi]], X2] *
 D[I2[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, \[CapitalPhi]], \[CapitalPhi]]];

A12 = FullSimplify[D[E1[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, \[CapitalPhi]], \[CapitalPhi]] *
 D[I1[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, \[CapitalPhi]], Y1] + 
 D[E1[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, \[CapitalPhi]], Y1] *
 D[I1[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, \[CapitalPhi]], \[CapitalPhi]] + 
 D[E2[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, \[CapitalPhi]], \[CapitalPhi]] *
 D[I2[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, \[CapitalPhi]], Y1] + 
 D[E2[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, \[CapitalPhi]], Y1] *
 D[I2[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, \[CapitalPhi]], \[CapitalPhi]]];

A13 = FullSimplify[D[E1[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, \[CapitalPhi]], \[CapitalPhi]] *
 D[I1[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, \[CapitalPhi]], Y2] + 
 D[E1[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, \[CapitalPhi]], Y2] *
 D[I1[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, \[CapitalPhi]], \[CapitalPhi]] + 
 D[E2[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, \[CapitalPhi]], \[CapitalPhi]] *
 D[I2[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, \[CapitalPhi]], Y2] + 
 D[E2[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, \[CapitalPhi]], Y2] *
 D[I2[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, \[CapitalPhi]], \[CapitalPhi]]];

A14 = FullSimplify[D[E1[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, \[CapitalPhi]], X1] *
 D[I1[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, \[CapitalPhi]], Y1] + 
 D[E1[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, \[CapitalPhi]], Y1] *
 D[I1[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, \[CapitalPhi]], X1] + 
 D[E2[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, \[CapitalPhi]], X1] *
 D[I2[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, \[CapitalPhi]], Y1] + 
 D[E2[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, \[CapitalPhi]], Y1] *
 D[I2[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, \[CapitalPhi]], X1]];

A15 = FullSimplify[D[E1[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, \[CapitalPhi]], X2] *
 D[I1[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, \[CapitalPhi]], Y2] + 
 D[E1[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, \[CapitalPhi]], Y2] *
 D[I1[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, \[CapitalPhi]], X2] + 
 D[E2[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, \[CapitalPhi]], X2] *
 D[I2[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, \[CapitalPhi]], Y2] + 
 D[E2[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, \[CapitalPhi]], Y2] *
 D[I2[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, \[CapitalPhi]], X2]];
```

The fourth chuck of code...

```
h = FullSimplify[E1[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, \[CapitalPhi]] *
 I1[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, \[CapitalPhi]] + 
 E2[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, \[CapitalPhi]] *
 I2[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, \[CapitalPhi]]];
```

The solution generating code...

```
FullSimplify[h*A14] 
FullSimplify[h*A15]
```

I posted an image since the cleanliness of the output is hard to capture otherwise.  The image is a little weak, but the output is generated...

[image]

I magnified the output image a little in hopes of more clarity...
[image]